# Robolectric Customizing ShadowSQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric

Started using Robolectric a while ago and I'm currently running in some issues creating my own shadow objects. I've written some code that tests the behavior of my customized SQLiteOpenHelper class which basically only calls the onCreate methods of my database tables.

```
@RunWith(SharedDatabaseHelperTestRunner.class)
public class SharedDatabaseHelperTest {

    private SharedDatabaseHelper helper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() 
            throws Exception {
        helper = new SharedDatabaseHelper(Robolectric.application);


    @Test
    public void shouldCallOnCreateOfDatabaseTables() 
            throws Exception {
        helper.onCreate(null);

        assertTrue(ShadowTweetTable.onCreateCalled);
    }

    @Test 
    public void shouldCallOnUpdateOfDatabaseTables() 
            throws Exception {
        helper.onUpgrade(null, 0, 0);

        assertTrue(ShadowTweetTable.onUpgradeCalled);
    }
```

The shadow object of the database table only sets some boolean variables too ensure onCreate is called:

```
@Implements(TweetTable.class)

public class ShadowTweetTable {

    public static boolean onCreateCalled = false;
    public static boolean onUpgradeCalled = false;

    @Implementation
    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        onCreateCalled = true;
    }

    @Implementation
    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgradeCalled = true;
    }
```

When I'm running the tests the RobolectricTestRunner tells me that TweetTable has no shadow field eventhough my customized testrunner bind my shadow class:

public class SharedDatabaseHelperTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

```
public SharedDatabaseHelperTestRunner(Class<?> testClass)
        throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
}

@Override
protected void bindShadowClasses() {
    Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowTweetTable.class);
}
```

}

Comment: well you are binding ShadowTweetTable but it complains about TweetTable - could that be a culprit? And where is @Implements defined?

Comment: I resolved the problem by changing the design. My SharedDatabaseHelper gets a List of table interfaces when its constructor is called.